# Convert python post request to php/curl

Tags: python, php, curl

I have a python script I have modified and it is working correctly. It just posts an xml file to a url (using basic authentication) and saves the xml response.

The environment that I need it on does not support python in that way (no cgi support, no system level access) so I am attempting to convert it to php. I think I am close, but I am just getting an error 500 from the api I am posting to with no other details.

I have intentionally entered a different password and the response changes to tell me it is not authorized, so I know the authorization is working correctly.

I've obviously change the URL to something generic in this post

**My working python:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests

def handle_failure(response):
    if response.status_code == 401:
        print("Export failed: invalid authentication. "
          "Please check username and password")
    elif response.status_code == 400 and "NO REPORTS FOUND" in response.text:
        print("No reports matched the search parameters.")
    else:
        print("Export failed.")
        print("HTTP code:", response.status_code)
        print("Response body:", response.text)

def export(username, password, filename=None):
    files = {
        "xmlRequest": open("uuid.xml", "rb")
    }
    url = "https://url.com/rest-service/report/export/xml"
    try:
        response = requests.post(
            url,
            auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(username, password),
            files=files)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print("Error: can't connect to", url)
        return
    if response.ok:
        if filename is None:
            print(response.text)
        else:
            with open(filename, "w") as f:
                f.write(response.text)
            print("Success. Response written to " + filename + ".")
    else:
    handle_failure(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    export("username", "password", "thereport.xml")
```

**My Current PHP:**

```
<?php

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://url.com/rest-service/report/export/xml");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$data = '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request>
    <export-report>
        <report mode="original"/>
        <search path="report.uuid" value="43109950-adsfa-4524f6-bfc4-adsfafeasd" operator="eq" datatype="string" conjunction="true" />
    </export-report>
</request>
';

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print_r($info);

echo $resp;

echo 'complete';
?>
```

**The Curl response from PHP:**

```
Array
(
[url] => https://url.com/rest-service/report/export/xml
[content_type] => text/html;charset=UTF-8
[http_code] => 500
[header_size] => 859
[request_size] => 210
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0.797376
[namelookup_time] => 0.049275
[connect_time] => 0.05067
[pretransfer_time] => 0.358989
[size_upload] => 270
[size_download] => 346
[speed_download] => 433
[speed_upload] => 338
[download_content_length] => 346
[upload_content_length] => 270
[starttransfer_time] => 0.359038
[redirect_time] => 0
[redirect_url] => 
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[primary_port] => 443
[local_port] => 54178
[http_version] => 3
[protocol] => 2
[ssl_verifyresult] => 0
[scheme] => HTTPS
[appconnect_time_us] => 358591
[connect_time_us] => 50670
[namelookup_time_us] => 49275
[pretransfer_time_us] => 358989
[redirect_time_us] => 0
[starttransfer_time_us] => 359038
[total_time_us] => 797376
)
```

**This curl command works, so I basically just need to recreate this in PHP:**

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://url.com/rest-service/report/export/xml' \
  -H 'accept: text/xml' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -u "username:password" \
  -F 'xmlRequest=@uuid.xml;type=text/xml'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Working solution in PHP:**

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://url/rest-service/report/export/xml');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'accept: text/xml',
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username:password');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    'xmlRequest' => new CURLFile('uuid.xml'),
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;

curl_close($ch);

?>
```